# SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor object has no attribute 'through'

Tags: python, django, debugging, model

Hi I've got the following Admin.py

```
from portfolio.models import LandingPage, Galleries
from django.contrib import admin

from mezzanine.pages.models import Page, RichTextPage, Link
from mezzanine.core.admin import DisplayableAdmin
from mezzanine.utils.urls import admin_url

class GalleriesInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model= Galleries.galleries.through

    list_display = ('galleries','thumb')
class PortfolioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
            (None,  {'fields':['gallerytitle']})
            ]
    inlines = [GalleriesInline]



admin.site.register(LandingPage, PortfolioAdmin)
```

Here's my model.py

```
from django.db import models
from mezzanine.pages.models import Page
from mezzanine.galleries.models import Gallery, GalleryImage


class LandingPage(models.Model):

    gallerytitle = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Galleries(LandingPage):
    landingpage = models.ForeignKey(LandingPage, related_name='lan_page')
    #galleriesthumb = models.ForeignKey(GalleriesThumb)
    tagline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery, related_name='gallerys')
    thumb = models.ManyToManyField(GalleryImage)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

When trying to add a new "LandingPage" via the admin I get:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/portfolio/landingpage/add/

Django Version: 1.4.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
['mezzanine.boot',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.redirects',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mezzanine.conf',
 'mezzanine.core',
 'mezzanine.generic',
 'mezzanine.blog',
 'mezzanine.forms',
 'mezzanine.pages',
 'mezzanine.galleries',
 'mezzanine.twitter',
 'portfolio',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.comments']
Installed Middleware:
['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.request.CurrentRequestMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForDeviceMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.TemplateForHostMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.core.middleware.AdminLoginInterfaceSelectorMiddleware',
 'mezzanine.pages.middleware.PageMiddleware']


Traceback:
File "/home/grumps/.virtualenvs/ofmax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/grumps/.virtualenvs/ofmax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/grumps/projects/ofmax/urls.py" in <module>
  8. admin.autodiscover()
File "/home/grumps/projects/ofmax/mezzanine/boot/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  76.     django_autodiscover(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/grumps/.virtualenvs/ofmax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py" in autodiscover
  29.             import_module('%s.admin' % app)
File "/home/grumps/.virtualenvs/ofmax/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/grumps/projects/ofmax/portfolio/admin.py" in <module>
  8. class GalleriesInline(admin.StackedInline):
File "/home/grumps/projects/ofmax/portfolio/admin.py" in GalleriesInline
  9.     model= Galleries.galleries.through

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/portfolio/landingpage/add/
Exception Value: 'SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'through'
```

I'm trying to set the admin up to display all instances of Gallery, and a single Gallery is selected to be able to select a GalleryImage related to Gallery

I apologize if this is a dumb question.  I'm new and I'm trying to work through this but I'm stuck.

Comment: Not overly familiar with Django, but you have `model= Galleries.galleries.through`, but your `Galleries` model only contains an attribute `gallery`, with a related named of `gallerys` ('s' instead of 'ies'). The issue may be in there somewhere (otherwise, not sure :) ).

Comment: @RocketDonkey thanks for the pointer... that got me going in the right direction.